# Flag bar button icon missing in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

I can't find the bar button icon looking like a flag in Xcode 6. I want to add it to a `UIBarButtonItem`. The reason I'm looking for one is that there is one in the iOS mail app. It's also shown on Apples HIG site: https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/BarIcons.html.